# CellContentClick does not fire on first row first column?

Tags: winforms, .net-3.5, datagridview

When I click the first cell in the first row of a dataGridView (0,0), the event, CellContentClick DOES NOT fire.  Is there a reason for this, or is it a bug?  If not a bug how can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 2):

**CellContentClick** event fires when you click on data that cell contains. If cell is empty and you click on it it will not fire.

If you know this already then explain with more clarification what exactly happening.

Comment: All cells have data, so it can't be that I don't think.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `DataGridView_CellClick` even there is no data in the cell.